# Handling concurrent requests with expired token react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, token, auth0

I'm encountering an issue with token management in my React Native application. When the token expires and multiple parallel requests are made, they all attempt to refresh the token. The first request succeeds, but subsequent requests fail with a "revoked refresh token" error since they use the expired token.

Below is the relevant code snippet:

```
let refreshTokenPromise: Promise<string> | null = null;

const refreshAuthToken = async () => {
  if (!refreshTokenPromise) {
    refreshTokenPromise = getCredentials().finally(() => {
      refreshTokenPromise = null;
    });
  }
  return await refreshTokenPromise;
};

// ... axiosInstance setup ...

const getCredentials = useCallback(async () => {
  const currentUnixTimestamp = moment().unix();
  if (userAccess.expirationTimeStamp < currentUnixTimestamp) {
    console.log('refreshing token', userAccess.accessObject?.refreshToken);
    return await refreshToken();
  }
  return userAccess.accessObject?.accessToken || '';
}, [userAccess, refreshToken]);
```

Here are the logs indicating the issue:

```
LOG  getting new token
LOG  refreshing token XXXX
LOG  getting new token
LOG  refreshing token XXXX
```

I expected the getCredentials function to execute only once when multiple requests are made after token expiration. However, as the logs show, it's being called multiple times.

I've attempted using an Axios interceptor to retrieve credentials before making API calls, but this approach also led to the same race condition.

I've seen similar issues resolved using methods like mine to prevent race conditions, but for some reason, it's not working in my case.

Any suggestions or insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I faced the same problem. What I did was identify both calls and add a conditional to request the token only once. Then I delayed the second call a couple of seconds. It's the only way I found to solve the problem. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

[SWR](https://github.com/vercel/swr) for example cache the request by an key parameter to dedupe the requests

Example: https://github.com/vercel/swr/blob/main/examples/basic/pages/index.js

```js
import Link from 'next/link'
import fetch from '../libs/fetch'

import useSWR from 'swr'

export default function Index() {
  const { data } = useSWR('/api/data', fetch) // First parameter is the request key which will prevent to execute several times

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
      <h1>Trending Projects!</h1>
      <div>
      {
        data ? data.map(project =>
          <p key={project}><Link href='/[user]/[repo]' as={`/${project}`}>{project}</Link></p>
        ) : 'loading...'
      }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```