# Expo-React-Native, Axios, RefreshToken, Expo-SecureStorage, Redux Toolkit - 2024

Tags: react-native, axios, jwt, expo, redux-toolkit

In my full-stack Expo React Native application, I am looking for ideas or sample code for handling JWT access and refresh tokens with Axios, Redux Toolkit, react-navigation/native, and Expo SecureStorage, specifically for scenarios involving app restarts,cold starts ,mutation and other api calls. I have developed the basic functionality, but I am facing an issue where Axios is sending its previous cached expired token or null to get a new refresh token or make other API calls when the Redux state is updated.

I am seeking ideas or sample javascript code for handling JWT access and refresh tokens with Axios, Redux Toolkit, and Expo SecureStorage  with proper approach.

Comment: I answered shortly a similar question regarding dedupe/in-flight requests (https://stackoverflow.com/a/78069470/5905466)